# Use of variable with Boolean data Type in EvalExpression in For Loop container in SSIS

Tags: variables, for-loop, ssis, boolean

I have a data flow task set in a For Loop Container. The loop should be executed for as long as the variable @LastPayment is not positive.

@LastPayment is a variable of DataType: Boolean, Value=False, EvaluateAsExpression=False and with the following set in Expression
"SELECT  [Continue]  FROM [DW_Test].[dbo].[Test]"

In my For Loop Editor, I have my EvalExpression set as : 
@[LastPayment]="1"

When I run the SSIS package, the Loop does not stop even though SELECT  [Continue]  FROM [DW_Test].[dbo].[Test] gives return of 0 after a few iteration, hence @[LastPayment]="1" is FALSE after a few iteration. I do not understand why the ForLoop is not ending.

When I changed the  EvalExpression to In my For Loop Editor to 
@[LastPayment]=(DT_BOOL)"TRUE" or @[LastPayment]="TRUE", I get the same results.

When I changed the  EvalExpression to In my For Loop Editor to @[LastPayment]="0"
No rows are generated.

Is there something wrong in my variable definition or the EvalExpression? Appreciate any advice on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update that I have resolved this.

Before the ForLoop process, I added a Execute SQL Task to determine the MaxLoop that the ForLoop process needs to go through and mapped the result set to variable @MaxLoop of datatype Int32.

In the ForLoop container, I added an expression task with expression @Loop=@Loop + 1. @Loop is a variable of datatype Int32. This is to count the number of loops the ForLoop has been processed.

My ForLoop EvalExpression is amended to @Loop<@MaxLoop.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

SSIS Booleans are not evaluated the same as SQL Server Bits.  The way to test if a Boolean variable is true is like this:

```
@[LastPayment] == true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check logical expression in a **For Loop**, you should write it as `@LastPayment<=0`. Microsoft explains [conditional expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141168.aspx).

Comment: Hi Ferdipux, are you suggesting to remove the "[" and "]" from the EvalExpression? I tried that but got the same results. So that wasn't the issue.

Comment: @JamieLim, replied to your previous version of question, where you write expressions as if LastPayment was a real value variable. For your current question, Tab's answer is correct. Or you can use simply `@LastPayment` since it is of Boolean type.